# Unable to find mlan0 wireless connection

Tags: debian, wifi, drivers, kernel-modules, wlan

This is happening on an Owasys microcontroller running Debian 9, yesterday I managed to get Wi-Fi turned on but today it does work and connection is not listed.

`lsmod`  returns a list of devices which does have mlan0 in it

```
Module                  Size  Used by
musb_dsps              20480  0
musb_hdrc              98304  1 musb_dsps
udc_core               28672  1 musb_hdrc
usbcore               204800  1 musb_hdrc
phy_am335x             16384  2
phy_am335x_control     16384  1 phy_am335x
phy_generic            16384  1 phy_am335x
usb_common             16384  5 phy_am335x,udc_core,musb_hdrc,musb_dsps,usbcore
c_can_platform         16384  0
c_can                  20480  1 c_can_platform
mcp251x                20480  0
snd_soc_tlv320aic31xx    36864  1
can_dev                24576  2 mcp251x,c_can
musb_am335x            16384  0
omap_wdt               16384  0
sd8xxx                552960  0
mlan                  430080  1 sd8xxx
cfg80211              266240  1 sd8xxx
ppp_generic            36864  0
slhc                   16384  1 ppp_generic
owa4x_gpio             16384  0
ip_tables              24576  0
x_tables               32768  1 ip_tables
```

but `iwconfig -a` does not list mlan0, which it did yesterday

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.8.244  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.8.255
        inet6 fe80::eb2:b7ff:fed8:9bd6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fdf4:7177:49ee:0:eb2:b7ff:fed8:9bd6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 0c:b2:b7:d8:9b:d6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 456  bytes 40141 (39.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 346  bytes 59107 (57.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 51  

eth0:0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.10.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        ether 0c:b2:b7:d8:9b:d6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        device interrupt 51  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

this is what I get if I run `dmesg`

```
[    5.939860] mlan: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    6.398869] systemd-journald[107]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[    6.418469] wlan: Loading MWLAN driver
[    6.480709] wlan: Driver loaded successfully
```

I suspect `loading out-of-tree module taints kernel` may be an issue but I do not know how to proceed further.

Comment: the logs tell the kernel module/driver has been loaded, not that this module actually detected your card. There would be additional logs about it

Comment: Also, the "taints the kernel" message is just informative, and just means you use a kernel module with possibly untrusted code. That's not connected to you seeing mlan0 or not.

Comment: @A.B how to you check that the module has detected the card? in all the logs there is no other mention of either mlan or wlan

Comment: Sorry but if I knew I would have told it. I searched on google and found examples with logs about mlan, each time there were additional logs about the card